# How to store coefficients in a .h file and use those coefficients in a .c function

Tags: c, header-files

I'm writing a C code that allows me to compute the results of a quadratic function.
So, for example, i wanna compute the result of a function like this:
k1*x1^2 + k2*x2^2 (quadratic terms) + k3*x1*x2 (mixed term) + k4*x1 + k5*x2 (linear terms) + k6 (constant term).

I've written:

- the .h file named "quadratic.h", that contains the definitions of the size of the vectors that will contain the coefficients (k1, k2,...) and the unknown values (x1 and x2) i have to use;
- the .c file "quadratic.c" that defines the function quadratic;
- the main file "main.c" that test the function.

In the "main.c" I've tested the correct working of the function with .txt files where i store the values of the coefficients k1, k2,... and the values of x1,x2.

What i wanna do and I'm having trouble with is to store the coefficients "k1, k2, ..." and the values "x1,x2" in 2 different header files and access to these 2 .h files within my function "quadratic.c".

I post the code I've written in case it may help understand the problem.
"quadratic.h":

```
#ifndef QUADRATIC_H_
#define QUADRATIC_H_

#include <stdio.h>

#define DIM_COV 2    // define the number of unknown parameters you have (x1,x2)
#define DIM_COEFF 2*DIM_COV+((DIM_COV*(DIM_COV-1)/2))+1   // the number of coefficients (k1,k2,...) 

#endif
```

"quadratic.c":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "quadratic.h"

float quadratic(float covariance_vec[DIM_COV], float coeff_vec[DIM_COEFF])
{
    int i, j;
    int coefficient_index=0;
    float quadratic_term = 0;
    float mix_term = 0;
    float linear_term = 0;
    float constant_term;
    float result;

    // compute the quadratic terms
    quadratic_loop : for (i=0; i<DIM_COV; i++)
    {
        quadratic_term = quadratic_term + covariance_vec[i]*covariance_vec[i]*coeff_vec[coefficient_index];
        coefficient_index++;
    }

    // compute the mixed terms
    mixed_loop : for (i=0; i<DIM_COV-1; i++)
    {
        mixed_inner_loop : for(j=i+1; j<DIM_COV; j++)
        {
            mix_term = mix_term + covariance_vec[i]*covariance_vec[j]*coeff_vec[coefficient_index];
            coefficient_index++;
        }
    }

    // compute the linear terms
    linear_loop : for (i=0; i<DIM_COV; i++)
    {
        linear_term = linear_term + covariance_vec[i]*coeff_vec[coefficient_index];
        coefficient_index++;
    }

    // constant term
    constant_term = coeff_vec[DIM_COEFF-1];

    return result = quadratic_term + mix_term + linear_term + constant_term;
}
```

"main.c". In the "cov_table.txt" and "coeff_table.txt" files i've stored the values of x1,x2 and the values of the coefficients k1,k2,... respectively:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "quadratic.h"

float quadratic(float covariance_vec[DIM_COV], float coeff_vec[DIM_COEFF]);

int main()
{

    int i;

    float v_cov[DIM_COV];
    float v_coeff[DIM_COEFF];

    FILE *FileCov;
    FILE *FileCoeff;

    FileCov = fopen("cov_table.txt","r");
    FileCoeff = fopen("coeff_table.txt","r");


    for (i=0; i<DIM_COV; i++)
    {
        fscanf(FileCov, "%f,", &v_cov[i]);
    }

    fclose(FileCov);

    for (i=0; i<DIM_COEFF; i++)
    {
        fscanf(FileCoeff, "%f,", &v_coeff[i]);
    }

    fclose(FileCoeff);

    float q_result = quadratic(v_cov, v_coeff);

    printf("The result of the quadratic function is: %f \n", q_result);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to look informations about how to store coefficients inside an .h file and use them inside an .c file, but i couldn't find anything useful.
The project requires i do it that way. So i MUST store the coefficients inside an .h file and use them.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: When you say "you're having trouble", can you be more precise? Is the syntax a problem? Do you get errors from the compiler or linker?

Comment: @Botje no syntax problem, no errors of any kind. The code i wrote work perfectly. I just don't know how i can "store" values inside an .h file and use them inside a .c file.

Comment: Then I am unclear what your question is. Did you manage to embed those arrays in your header file or not? If not, why not?

Comment: Be aware of `#define DIM_COEFF 2*DIM_COV+((DIM_COV*(DIM_COV-1)/2))+1` without full parenthesis, it works by chance (or is maybe wrong) here: `coeff_vec[DIM_COEFF-1]`

Comment: So yes, in fact, your question is "how do I define an array in C". Surely your textbook has mentioned something along the lines of `float foo[] = { ... } `?

Comment: @Botje So i just declare a series of arrays inside the .h file?

Comment: OT: what are the labels quadratic_loop, mixed_loop, mixed_inner_loop, linear_loop for? You seem to use them as a comment. If you want to put a comment, put a comment like `/* come comment */` or `// some comment`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I'm using Vitis HLS to convert C code into VHDL. The user guide suggest to name each loop so you can easily detect it when you are doing the test bench.

Comment: Sure. Although you probably want to make sure only a single definition of those arrays exist. The usual strategy is to *declare* in a header file and *define* in a C file, or hide the definition behind a macro that is only defined in a single .c file.

Comment: @Botje sorry I'm not understanding well. Let me try with an example. I wanna compute the result of this function: k1*x1^2 + k2*x2^2 + k3. The coefficient vector (CV) contains (k1,k2,k3) and the unknown vector (UV) contains (x1,x2). Lets suppose that CV = (1,1,1) and UV = (2,3). The results is 14 (4+9+1). I will store CV as an array in the cv.h file and UV as an array in the uv.h file? What if i wanna test my function with more CV and UV vectors? Do I have to use one array for each vector?

Comment: This is the point where you ask whoever made you do this for clarifications on "So i MUST store the coefficients inside an .h file and use them.". Depending on the answer your program will take different shapes. The interpretation I had until now was that you are required to store the *coefficients* of one or more polynomials in your header – effectively baking them into your program – in order for some user-facing code to evaluate inputs against one of those polynomials.

Comment: Storing arrays of data in the .h file is not the way to go.  You can reference the array name in the .h file, IE: "int my_array[]; "  -- But you don't do this in the .h file:   "int my_array[]={1,2,3,4,5}; " ...because duplicate data will be created each time you include the .h file... most compilers will catch this and fail the compile.